# SQL JOIN inside LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Is it possible to join a table inside a table join? If so how do I do it?

I have experience doing standard joins (LEFT JOIN) and have worked out how to join multiple tables but cant see how to join a table inside a table join. Here is my data structure to explain better:

```
T1 (
    T1_T2
)

T1_T2 (
    T1_T2_id
    T1_T2_T3
)

T1_T2_T3 (
    T1_T2_T3_id
    T1_T2_T3_a
    T1_T2_T3_b
)
```

Currently my SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
    LEFT JOIN T1_T2 
        ON T1.T1_T2 = T1_T2.T1_T2_id
```

This returns the data I want from T1 and T1_T2. I want to join T1_T2 on to T1_T2_T3 like so:

```
SELECT * FROM T1_T2
    LEFT JOIN T1_T2_T3 
        ON T1_T2.T1_T2_T3 = T1_T2_T3.T1_T2_T3_id
```

Can I do this in one query?

Comment: Add another (second) `JOIN` with third table

Comment: There should be no problem if you add another JOIN with the third table

Comment: Do you mean I can do:
SELECT * FROM T1
    LEFT JOIN T1_T2 
        ON T1.T1_T2 = T1_T2.T1_T2_id
    LEFT JOIN T1_T2_T3 
        ON T1_T2.T1_T2_T3 = T1_T2_T3.T1_T2_T3_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
    LEFT JOIN T1_T2 
     ON T1.T1_T2 = T1_T2.T1_T2_id
    LEFT JOIN T1_T2_T3 
     ON T1_T2.T1_T2_T3 = T1_T2_T3.T1_T2_T3_id
```

Comment: great thats working! did not realise it would be so simple! thanks, I will accept your answer when the time limit is up.

Comment: Yup! It was simple. And the query you wrote in comment is the same(but I saw it after posting answer), yet upvoted - Thank you for that.. :)

Comment: @MikeOram, did you check that answer, i think its not working